# An addition problem

Tags: mathematics

Considering that

> 50+20=60

and

> 60+30=72,

what's 40+30?

---

**Edit** (now that this has been answered, I can state): This was earlier posted to [`alt.usage.english`](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet) as part of its 2008 Summer Doldrums Competition. (I was the author of that puzzle.) [Google has an archive of the discussion at the time.](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/alt.usage.english/zlh8KtyFvMs/discussion)

Answer (score 10):

The answer is

> $58$

Because

> $a\star b = a + b - \frac{ab}{100}\\50\star20 = 50+20-5\times2 = 60\\60\star30 = 60+30 - 6\times3 = 72$

So

> $30\star40 = 30+40 - 3\times4 = 58$

Use of title and $+$ sign

> This is almost the same as the total $\%$ increase when a value is increased by $a\%$ and then by $b\%$ (that would be $a + b +\frac{ab}{100}$) so perhaps 'addition problem' refers to the incorrect sign? The $+$ would then be used to mean that the percents were 'added', but that feels like I'm just grasping at straws.

---

Note:
I've used $\star$ instead of $+$ as was used in the question to make the answer more clear to read - it is confusing to use $+$ as the symbol for both the addition operator and the 'mystery operator'.

Comment: Yes, excellent, that's the correct answer, and +1, but you haven't explained the use of the "+" (also alluded to, though weakly, in the title). Why is this called addition?

Comment: I honestly can't think of anything.

Comment: If you think of it and edit it in, then please ping me in a comment.

Comment: @msh210 that's the best I've got.

Answer (score 9):

KoA already gave the numerical answer, but here's the reasoning:

> The numbers are probabilities of events (or whatever), expressed as percentages. The addition operator represents "or" — that is, the probability of either two of the events occurring. Assuming the events are independent, the probability of either of them occurring is $a + b - a \times b$, or as percentages, $\left(\frac a{100} + \frac b{100} - \frac a{100} \times \frac b{100}\right)\times100$, which simplifies to the equation KoA gave.

Comment: That definitely seems much more plausible than what I said :D

Comment: Hm, that's a good explanation, +1; and not what I was thinking of. `:-)` I'm still hoping someone will come up with an answer that's more "additional".

Comment: The +1 is not because it explains the "addition" but because it's a step toward that explanation.

Comment: @msh210 man, I was *certain* about this one... the addition sign is commonly used when expressing this particular operation. I'm curious about what it turns out to be. Got a couple of ideas, but they're far more complicated and contrived.

Answer (score 6):

You're calling this addition because it's a form of "adding" discounts to sale prices.

A lot of outlet stores have advertised discounts of, say, 20% off everything in the store **plus** 50% off certain items. This results in a total discount of $1 - (1 - 20\%) (1 - 50\%) = 60\%$, rather than the 70% you'd get by adding things together straight.

If it's 30% off everything and 60% off a certain item, the total discount would 72% instead of 90%.

And 40% off plus 30% off would be 58% off, as some people have mentioned.

---

In fact, the real numbers in the interval $(0,1)$ form an abelian  semigroup (or a monoid if you include 0) under the operation $a + b - ab$, just like addition over the positive (/nonnegative for the monoid) real numbers. So it can rightfully be called "addition" in that way too.

Comment: Bravo! This is the addition. Now I'm torn as to whether to award you or KoA the checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

Or it could be

> $60$

with

> $a\star b = 6\left(3+\dfrac{a+b}{10}\right)$

Comment: Yeah, all sorts of arithmetic formulas are possible but, as I commented on the other answers, there's a reason I called it addition.